# mod_wsgi with python 3.9

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi, python-3.9

I tried to install `mod_wsgi` with python3.9 and I encountered the following problem:

```
Collecting mod_wsgi
  Using cached mod_wsgi-4.9.0.tar.gz (497 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Abderrahim\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vyvmq_yd\mod-wsgi_44a42999c6a1497587de7d892a9a5a00\setup.py", line 81, in <module>
          raise RuntimeError('No Apache installation can be found. Set the '
      RuntimeError: No Apache installation can be found. Set the MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR environment to its location.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

knowing that I have already installed visual studio build tools,
i need help please

Answer (score 1):

see the installation description here:

https://pypi.org/project/mod-wsgi/

"If you are on Windows and your Apache distribution is not installed into the directory C:/Apache24, first set the environment variable MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR to the directory containing the Apache distribution"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mod_wsgi for Apache2, it may be better to use Python 3.6 instead of Python 3.9. by default mod_wsgi is for python3.6